# Adding fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I'm trying to allow user to add and remove email fields in my view using jquery. Whenever either link is click nothing happens.

html/cshtml

```
<div id="emailSection">
  <ul>
    <li>Email(s) to send notice to.</li>
     <li><input type="email" name="emails[]" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>
     <li><a class="add_email_button ui-button" href="#" >Add Another Email</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
           ...
            $('.remove_field').on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('li').remove();
            });
            $('.add_email_button').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).insertBefore('<li><input type="email" name="emails[]" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>');
            });
        }
    );

</script>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjkq9oes/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insertbefore must be used on the other way :

```
$(/* What you need to insert */ ).insertBefore(/* Before what ?*/);
```

In your case you must use like that :

```
var html = '<li><input type="email" name="emails[]" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>';
$(html).insertBefore( $(this) );
```

Works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/yj6ydbgp/

---------[ EDIT ]------------

For the remove:

1/ You need to create an event on parent, to check all new remove button (or they'll not get click event after creation).

2/ You waqnt delete the < li > parent, and not the < div > parent.

New, working for Add and Remove
http://jsfiddle.net/yj6ydbgp/1/

Comment: Below I have given a small comparison of closest() vs parent().
Have a look, this is huge performance solver when you are looking at some 100000 lines of elements.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of minor problems (where you added the new items and what you remove - wrong parent), but the main one is that you should use delegated event handlers for the click events. They do not care if the elements are added later.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/yj6ydbgp/3/

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#emailSection').on('click', '.remove_field', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });
        $('.add_email_button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('<li><input type="email" name="emails[]" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>').insertBefore(this);
        });
    }
);
```

They work by listing for events (click in this instance) bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor element (`document` is the default if none is convenient), *then* applying the selector, *then* applying your function to *any elements that caused the event*. In your case you could use `$('#emailSection').on` as it is the closest non-changing ancestor.

This is more efficient in most cases as well, as the selector is only applied at event time, and only to the chain of elements that it bubbles up through. Where elements are added dynamically delegated event handlers are the best way to handle events.

Comment: You don't need it for 'add' because it'll never been removed/added

Comment: @Arthur: true, but I tend to always use delegated `on` as habit. More flexible to changes.

Comment: It's too heavy for the Js like that, cause for each click event triggered on document, jquery will test all children to know if it's a .add_email_button element.
So use it with moderation ;)

Comment: @Arthur: If you study the code behind jQuery you will find the selector is actually lighter as it only touches the elements in the bubble branch. Besides, this is in response to a click event so unless you click 50,000 times a second you will not care :) You should also note this is attached to `#emailSection` so is even more efficient.

Comment: Hoo Good to know ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this should work, and here is some extra information :

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(document).on("click", '.remove_field' , function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });
        $('.add_email_button').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var html = '<li><input type="email" name="emails[]" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>';
            $(html).insertBefore( $(this) );
        });
    }
);
```

Note the other alternatives for remove

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

No you know when to use what.

closest()  http://api.jquery.com/closest/

parent() http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Aside from copying the code from one of the other answer's JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yj6ydbgp/1/), this did not really add anything new.

Comment: Thats where I mentioned the last two lines which DEFINITELY added something new.

Comment: The point being *copying without referencing the source is plagiarism*. Your addition was best suited to a comment on the other person's answer as is it trivial. The hard work of fixing the actual 3 issues was done by others.